# Reading an Excel Sheet containing 10000 Rows In C#

Tags: c#, excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading Excel Files as a Server Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273116/reading-excel-files-as-a-server-process)

While the Jet OleDB Driver is pretty simple to use for reading an Excel sheet, it simply cant handle excel files having rows more than a thousand.

Is there any other way of reading more than 5-10k rows from an excel sheet in C#?

Comment: I used the Jet OleDB Driver in the past and read many more than a thousand rows....

Comment: I also have used the oledb driver on thousands of rows, what exactly is your current issue?

Comment: The issue is with the speed and also if the no of rows crosses 10k i get an exception which says the connection is lost.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an ooxml file you can use [open xml sdk](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0&displaylang=en). It is not as straightforward as the oledb driver, but it is possible.

If you can transform the excel-sheet to a csv-file, you can use [Filehelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/). This can handle 100K+ records.