# Excel import to database using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Hi please find the screenshot attached and provide me the logic how we can acheive this. I need to import this excel file. This is a sample image. I have no. of header rows and no. of columns will differ in each header.
[image]

Here is another information about the excel file.
Col cells are set with background color. IS there any way to read the values from the cells having background color

Comment: why use C#? why not go straight to the DB? if you're using Sql Server you can use SSIS.

Comment: Sqlserver. No i can't go for SSIS. I need to use asp.net and c#, since i need to implement in sharepoint application

Comment: well say that, will reduce more questions.

Answer (score 0):

Suggests that you probably want to do this in an automated way. I posted a [question + analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273116/reading-excel-files-as-a-server-process) of a number of ways to do this using 3rd party libraries (as the Interop isn't really designed for automation).

I'd recommend a library (something like [FlexCel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp)) or using some of the newer capabilities in C# to handle the Office XML format. Believe these are avaliable from .NET 3.5 onwards but I don't know much about them.