# ASP.NET creates Excel file through Visual Studio but fails with IIS

Tags: c#, excel, iis

Piece of code below works fine with Development Server but fails when the project is published to IIS. Tried different ones than the `xlExcel8`  but no help. I also thought changing `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` reference's "Copy Local" property to "True" but it's grayed out. I am not able to change it. I suspect the IIS and Visual Studio using different dlls.

```
_excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(filename, XlFileFormat.xlExcel8)
```

Comment: You do realize that the Excel interop is not designed for - and Microsoft specifically say "Do not use" in an IIS context?

Comment: Please see my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273116/reading-excel-files-as-a-server-process regarding using Excel on a server. It includes a link from Microsoft as to why you shouldn't do it using the Interop.

Comment: OK. Accept all. But, just to test I have installed VS2012 on the server and it worked properly. Makes sense or not?

Comment: @Ian Do you think it's a good idea to develop a Windows Project for that.

Comment: @Jude: I would pick a library that you can use instead that will work safely within IIS. It's incredibly difficult to get native Excel to behave - and it varies across server operating systems. It really isn't worth the hassle trying. I used FlexCel previously, quite cheap and worked really well.

Comment: OK. I will go for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Well. Let's start with the fact that running office in a server environment is not supported? And an IIS application pool sort of is exactly hat. Contrary to your dev server - running in your UI session  - it also has no UI session it runs in.

And that pretty much is it.

Not supported. Whoever came up with this idea - did not check whether it is feasible.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question - it should be a comment.

Comment: Actually it is an answer. Do not do it, it is not fixable and it is not going to work, ever. THere is no other answer.

Comment: That's not strictly too - before I was unaware of the reasons not to do it, the product I used to be involved in did so and it worked reasonably well. I however switched it to use a 3rd party library instead when I came across that advice.

Comment: What are comments for then TomTom?

Comment: @Juse commenting. You may want to use a dictionary to get the terms "answer" and "comment" defined - you seem to lack some language understading (on top of working on a design that is not supposed to even work).

Comment: I suppose you need that said dictionary

Answer (score -1):

Just FYI,

For reasons I'd rather not get into, I am running interop on IIS and it works fine.  I'm not saying I'd recommend using it, and I plan on switching to OpenXL, but for those saying it doesn't work and there's no other answer, they are quite wrong.