# Can't open the excel file after generating it on server side

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have generated the excel file using C# coding as shown below

**C# Coding:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var doc = new SpreadsheetDocument(@"D:\JOSEPH\GenerateExcelSheet\OpenXmlPackaging.xlsx");
            Worksheet sheet1 = doc.Worksheets.Add("My Sheet");
            sheet1.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Test";

            sheet1.Cells["A1"].Value = 1;
            sheet1.Cells["C3"].Style = new OpenXmlPackaging.Style {

                Borders = new Borders(BorderStyles.Thick),
                Font = new Font
                {
                    Name = "Consolas",
                    Size = 10,
                    Style = FontStyles.DoubleUnderline | FontStyles.Bold
                },
                NumberFormat = new NumberFormat("#,##0.0;[Red](#,##0.0)"),
                Alignment = new Alignment
                {
                    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right,
                    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
                    WrapText = true,
                    Rotation = 45
                },
            };
            sheet1.Cells.CreateRange("B10:D5").MergeCells();
            sheet1.AutoFitColumns();
            sheet1.SetColumnWidth(3, 12);


        }
```

but when i tried to open the excel file, a message box appears as " [image]"

Comment: Just recommendation: Next time crop the message box instead of uploading whole screenshot so it's easier to read ;) Btw in what version of Excel are you opening it?

Comment: What happens here if 2 people call the page at the same time? Madness ensues!

Comment: Ok sure... @Ms.Nobody

Comment: MS Excel 2010 @Ms.Nobody

Comment: @DavidG: Absolutely - reason why I added my answer where Microsoft simply say don't do it!

Comment: @Ian And that's why you got my +1 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you shouldn't be trying to create an Excel file on the server like this. There are technical issues and licensing issues of using the Excel API to do this - you can read more here http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/257757

The technical problems may well explain why you're file is corrupt.

The better approach would be to use a library that doesn't rely on the Excel API, I listed a few in my question/answer here [Reading Excel Files as a Server Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273116/reading-excel-files-as-a-server-process) that may help you.

Comment: @JoeMike: I only summarized the ones I was able to investigate and try at the time. Outside of that list I don't know I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for open Excel:

```
     ApplicationClass excel = new ApplicationClass();
            Worksheet sheet1  = Activate(excel);
//insert you'r code
```

Use this for save and close Excel:

```
 excel.Visible = true;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    sheet1.SaveAs(filename, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
                    excel.Application.Quit();
                    excel.Quit();

                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ws);
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
                    excel = null;
```